# How to get all files from all folders in JSON from Google Drive API in Java

Tags: java, json, google-drive-api

Is there any chance to get all files in all folders in JSON using Google Drive API, just simple with sending GET method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. You can use `files.list`. 
This is the corresponding GET request, which returns all files by default.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files
```

Take a closer look [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list). There is also an online demo to test it.

The Java code for this request could look like this:

```
private static List<File> retrieveAllFiles(Drive service) throws IOException {
    List<File> result = new ArrayList<File>();
    Files.List request = service.files().list();

    do {
      try {
        FileList files = request.execute();

        result.addAll(files.getItems());
        request.setPageToken(files.getNextPageToken());
      } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
        request.setPageToken(null);
      }
    } while (request.getPageToken() != null &&
             request.getPageToken().length() > 0);

    return result;
  }
```